# Filter the output of regulaer expression

Tags: java, regex

I am using a regular expression to extract content from a txt file. I have two questions. Now i have a code that can do the regular expression for me but it requires more memory. So how can i improve my current code to use minimum memory. Other question is that i want to filer (get some part of the current regular expression result). For ex: my current code gives part= 324324234 and i want to filter it and get only the number. to get the part number it is a must to use this regular expression and now i want to filter the output. So how can i do this. Please help me to overcome this issue. Any help would be much appriciated. Here is my current regular expression code:

```
public class RegularExpression_fyp{

    public static void main(String [] argv) throws Exception {
        String pattern = "\\part\\=\\w[0-9 ]+";

        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

        FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("F:\\testing1.txt");
        FileChannel channel = input.getChannel();

        ByteBuffer bbuf = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, (int) channel.size());
        CharBuffer cbuf = Charset.forName("8859_1").newDecoder().decode(bbuf);

        Matcher matcher = r.matcher(cbuf);

        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Found value: " + matcher.group(0));
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("NO MATCH");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use lookbehind to test the string before digits: `(?<=\\part\\[ ]=[ ])[0-9]+`

Answer (score 0):

Get the number after the string `part=` from group index 1.

```
part\\s*=\\s*([0-9]+)
```

Code:

```
String s = "foo bar part= 324324234 foo bar";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("part\\s*=\\s*([0-9]+)");
 Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(s);
 while(matcher.find()){
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Output:

```
324324234
```

Comment: do you have any suggesions to improve my code? Thank you for your contribution.

Comment: here everytime the number is different and i do have to run this code several times as well. so that is why i have used part= .

Comment: it would match any number which was present just after to `part=`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a concern about memory, any regular expression that uses **groups** will consume more memory than those that don't.

> Capturing groups are a way to treat multiple characters as a single unit. They are created by placing the characters to be grouped inside a set of parentheses. For example, the regular expression `([0-9)` creates a single group containing the numbers from 0 to 9. The portion of the input string that matches the capturing group will be saved in memory for later recall via back references.

You could achieve the same using look behind by doing `(?<=part=\s)\d+`; this version will match the same result the numbers using less memory.

However, I noticed your expression above considered the possibility of space between the numbers if that is necessary the expression needs to be:
`(?<=part=\s)[0-9 ]+`. Another important thing to mention is the use `\w` prior to your numbers since `\w` matches `[0-9A-Za-z_]` and it seems that your expression wants to consider an space instead.